# How to convert a string factor into Date?

Tags: r, date

I'm working with the London crime dataset which contains dates in an integer format. I melted them and now they have become `factor`s.

For example, `"X200801"`. I want to convert it into `"1/1/2008"`.

I know `as.Date` is used to convert different types into date format but still, I am a bit confused with this format of date which is provided in data set i.e `"X200801"`.

This is my structure

[image]

Comment: Just remove the X with any replacing function eg `gsub` and proceed. Alternatively, find out what the source of this X is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to use `lubridate`

```
ss <- factor("X200801")

library(lubridate)
ymd(paste(sub("X", "", ss), "01", sep = ""))
#[1] "2008-01-01"
```

Comment: I tried using lubridate, The following object is masked from package:base : base

Comment: I assume the warning refers to `date` (not base) being masked by `lubridate`. That's just a notice that function `date` is now from `lubridate` (instead of base R).

Answer (score 4):

Using base R we can add the date component using `paste0` convert to date object using appropriate `format`.

```
as.Date(paste0("X200801", "01"), format = "X%Y%m%d")
#[1] "2008-01-01"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `anytime`:

```
test=as.factor("X200801")
library(anytime)
anydate((gsub("X","",test)))
[1] "2008-01-01"
```

As suggested by @akrun we can simply supply a format that will be used  within our environment with `addFormats` and use `anydate` to convert to date:

```
addFormats("X%Y%m")
anydate("X200801")
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction.(Vote limit reached). @akrun

Answer (score 1):

It can be compactly changed with `as.yearmon`

```
library(zoo)
as.Date(as.yearmon("X200801", "X%Y%m"))
#[1] "2008-01-01"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use parse_datetime from the readr package: 
`testdate <- factor("X200801")`
`parse_datetime(as.character(testdate), format = 'X%Y%M')`

I wouldn't recommend using MM/DD/YYY in R. Keeping things in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format is preferable.